# LDR - Literal pool - ARM

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, arm

I know how to load an immediate value using the LDR instruction in ARM.

For example:

`LDR R0,=0x0804c088`
This instruction loads the value (`0x0804c088`) to the register `r0`. When I try to access the address it is stored in using `x/x $r0` using `gdb`. I get the message: `Cannot access memory at address`0x0804c088. But that is not the address, it is the value stored in that register and the address is a `PC` relative address which is stored in the literal pool.

What is the mistake that I doing there? did I understand something wrong there?

Moreover, How should I set the literal pool, can you give me an example please?

@Carl Norum: Here is the code.

```
__asm__("LDR R0,=0x0804c088");
__asm__("LDR R1,[PC, #34];");
```

O/p from gdb

```
(gdb) info registers
r0             0x804c088        134529160
r1             0xf2c00300       4072669952
r2             0x0      0
r3             0x1      1
r4             0x8961   35169
r5             0x0      0
r6             0x0      0
r7             0xbe8f4b74       3197062004
r8             0x0      0
r9             0xef99   61337
r10            0xf00d   61453
r11            0x0      0
r12            0x0      0
sp             0xbe8f4b74       0xbe8f4b74
lr             0x89a7   35239
pc             0x8a62   0x8a62 <test46+34>
cpsr           0x60000030       1610612784
(gdb) x/x $r0
0x804c088:      Cannot access memory at address 0x804c088
(gdb) p/x$r0
$1 = 0x804c088
(gdb) p/x $r1
$2 = 0xf2c00300
(gdb) x/x $r1
0xf2c00300:     Cannot access memory at address 0xf2c00300
(gdb) x/x $r15
0x8a62 <test46+34>:     0x1022f8df
```

Comment: @Jake'Alquimista'LEE : so it is *possible*.  The question is very unclear.  You got a meaning from it I didn't consider; which is valid and interesting, but not very useful for anything.  In the other question, I asked to describe the higher level purpose of what **pistal** is trying to do.  He seems very confused about assembler to me.

Comment: Agreed, the OP seems to be confused. He want's to know something that he doesn't have to, for whatever the reason might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gdb `x` command has an inherent dereferencing operation.  If you want to print the value in `r0`, just use `p`:

```
p/x $r0
```

The form of `LDR` you're using isn't a real instruction - it's an assembler macro-instruction that gets converted into a pc-relative `ldr` instruction and a literal value someplace in memory (probably close to the location you're using it).  If you want to find the address of the constant in the literal pool, you need to look at the output binary.  Your source assembly code doesn't contain it.

For example, let's take this simple example program:

```
    .globl f
f:
    ldr r0,=0x12345678
```

And then build and disassemble it:

```
$ arm-none-eabi-clang -c example.s 
$ arm-none-eabi-objdump -d example.o 

example.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <f>:
   0:   e51f0004    ldr r0, [pc, #-4]   ; 4 <f+0x4>
   4:   12345678    .word   0x12345678
```

You can see the literal is right there at offset `4`.

You don't need to do anything to "set up the literal pool".  Any necessary literals will be set up for you by the assembler.

Comment: I checked the register 15, that is, `PC`. and it gives me a value <test+34>. But, when I tried to load the value from that place, that is, `LDR R1,[R0, #34]`. It throws a seg. fault.

Comment: I thought you said `r0` wasn't a pointer?  Why are you trying to deference it?

Comment: My mistake. But the value in `R1` is not the same as `R0`. I checked that using `gdb`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you expect it to be.  Can you show your actual code so I can help you figure out what wrong?

Comment: When I am pointing to the address of `R0` and loading the value from it, to the register `R1`. I expect the value to be the same. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: R0 is a register.  It has no address.  It sounds like you have some fundamental confusion about what's going on.  Again, if you show your actual code, I might be able to clear up some problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33567/discussion-between-pistal-and-carl-norum)

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't make any sense.  What makes you think that 34 is even a reasonable number to put there?  I think you need to go back to basics on this stuff.

Comment: I started reading the ARM Ref. Manual. Maybe that should give a better insight.

Comment: @pistal, I'm not sure the ARM reference is a good place to learn this kind of stuff. It talks a lot about the instruction set, but not that much about the behaviour of particular assemblers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know the actual address of the literal pool at runtime, try this :

```
adr r12, literal_pool_label
.
.
. // your code here
.
.
.
literal_pool_label:
.ltorg
```

Then you can read r12 which contains the address of the literal pool at runtime.

ltorg is a directive forcing where the literal pool is placed. For short codes, they are automatically attached at the end of the code, but if the code gets larger than 4KB, the LDR pseudo instruction will cause an error at assembly time since the pc-relative offset gets bigger than 4096, and thus out of allowed range.

To avoid this, you can put ltorg middle in the code where it's safe from being misinterpreted as an instruction. (after an absolute branch for example)